# How to recover a file replaced by empty one with > in Linux?

Tags: linux, file-recovery

I ran pv command as `pv /path/file1 > file1` and did not notice that I am in the same directory as 'path' so the input file is actually the output file

pv gave me a message:

> pv: input file is output file: /path/file1

but shell truncated the file to zero size

Is it possible to recover this file somehow?

OS: Debian 8

Comment: If you use `dd` to copy the raw file partition to a file, then you may be able to find some of the file in the free space, provided it hasn't been reallocated to another file. Otherwise, you might recover some of it with a simple C program which opens the file in append mode, positions to a large byte number, then writes a byte and closes it. If neither of these approaches finds anything, then you'll need to recover from back-up; if it wasn't backed up, then it wasn't very important (by definition).

Comment: Technical note on "`pv` gave me a message [...] but it truncated the file to zero size": it's the shell what truncated the file; `pv` saw it already truncated.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to recover the file with extundelete

Here is what I did

- STOP using the operating system immediately or remount the partition as read only if it is not used by any process (I was lucky that the path where my file was located was on a separate partition and not actively used)
- boot from a rescue system or stay on the current system if you are sure no process will use the partition you are recovering from without your knowledge
- backup whole partition (with `dd` for example)
- install `extundelete`
- remount the partition as read/write
- delete the empty file (note the path and the name of the file)
- `cd` to a directory on a different partition as one you are recovering from (make sure there is enough space for the recovered file)
- unmount the partition
- run `extundelete path/to/disk/label --restore-file path/to/deleted/file` (for example `extundelete /dev/sdb1 --restore-file documents/important.txt`)
- the recovered file should appear in RECOVERED_FILES directory